# Convert annotations to Grease Pencil object (old GP to new GP)

Tags: grease-pencil

I'm playing with the new version of Blender (Beta 2.8) and was wondering how I could open/import old Grease Pencil animations (done before the 2.8), which are now called *annotations* if I understood correctly - and load them into the new Blender as Grease Pencil objects ?

Thanks

Comment: In Blender 2.8, use F3 - Convert To Grease Pencil which will convert annotation to a GP , select the newly created GP then edit its material (stroke/color) in the properties panel for it to be visible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out and it's quite easy:

1. In object mode, show the right sidebar of the window by clicking `n`.
2. In the Annotations section, check which is the name of your (old) Grease Pencil datablock. For ease of reading, rename it *OLD_GP*.

[image]

3. Create an empty Grease Pencil object (`SHIFT+A` > *Grease Pencil* > *Blank*)
4. In the properties panel of that object, go to the *Grease Pencil* tab.
5. Load the datablock that we have previously renamed *OLD_GP*.

[image]

Now we need to assign a material to the Grease Pencil because it it currently "invisible" :

6. Go to the *materials* tab and click *New*.

[image]

Et voilà !

7. You can now remove the datablock from the annotations.

[image]

Comment: Looks like it is not working anymore as of 2.8 2019/04/08