# Convert Annotations to Grease Pencil

Tags: grease-pencil

There is obviously an answer to the question of converting GPencil from 2.79 to 2.8 here. [Convert old GP to new GP](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/118079/convert-annotations-to-grease-pencil-object-old-gp-to-new-gp)

And this works but only if you open a 2.79 file with Gpencil in it. The Gpencil shows as annotations and you can use the same datablock on a Gpencil object.

However if you create an annotation inside of 2.8 you can't use the same datablock for the Gpencil.

I don't know if this is a bug or intended but it sucks :-)

Does anybody know of this issue and can help me report it to a dev? Or is there a solution?

Answer (score 3):

Press <kbd>F3</kbd> , then convert grease pencil

Comment: Note that stopping after "Convert to grease pencil" may end up in an invisible object. you then have to edit the GP material stroke color in the properties tab to make it visible.

Comment: "Convert Grease Pencil" isn't appearing in that list for me.