# Grease Pencil Backwards compatibility or import function?

Tags: grease-pencil

Wanting to find a way to import old GP layer from 2.79 into 2.8 beta. At the moment if i open the .blend file the GP data is shown however there doesn't seem to be any way to select or edit the data. Wondering if anyone has found a work arou

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert annotations to Grease Pencil object (old GP to new GP)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/118079/convert-annotations-to-grease-pencil-object-old-gp-to-new-gp)

Answer (score 1):

AH, i figured out a workaround in the meantime for anyone looking for the same thing. Basically the issue is that the old GP data is being brough in as an annotation rather than a GP object. I found an answer to this issue here 
[Convert annotations to Grease Pencil object (old GP to new GP)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/118079/convert-annotations-to-grease-pencil-object-old-gp-to-new-gp)